# C# Dependency Injection with Unity, a unit of work, a database and the ability to change database at runtime

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, api, model-view-controller

So I am wrestling with this for quite some time now, but I can't seem to figure it out.
At first I had a datalayer in my solution. This layer is for the communication between the business and the database. It had a generic repository and context objects so it is easy to retrieve and send data from and to the database with EntityFrameWork 6. This all worked very good... but...

Now I notice that in my application (WebAPI 2) I need to change database at runtime. This is really hard to do. It should follow this path:
An external application does a call to my API. In the header of the request is set which database should be used (an Id, or a logic name or whatever, not important now). Before an action is executed some code should read this header-item and set the new connection to the repositories.

This is how I register the repositories for Unity:

```
container.RegisterType<IContexts.ILanguageCodes<LanguageCode>, Data.LanguageCodes>();
container.RegisterType<IContexts.ISecurityRoles<SecurityRole>, Data.SecurityRoles>();
```

To show you everything what the implementations of these interfaces are is very much.

To change the connection to an other database I have to change the DBContext, which I know where to find, but the code doesn't. So I started Googling.

Then I found this article: http://rob.conery.io/2014/03/04/repositories-and-unitofwork-are-not-a-good-idea/. I read it and all the stuff that is not good is in my project. I was like: Okay, lets start over on the datalayer.

THen I found this article: https://www.danylkoweb.com/Blog/a-better-entity-framework-unit-of-work-pattern-DD. I followed this and came pretty far. But got stuck on the part where the request comes in.

So basicly I am looking for this:
A way to change the connection to an other database at runtime with dependency injection, so I don't have to change the connection everywhere. In the end; the idea of DI is that you don't know where the implementation is, so in this case you don't know where all the connections are.
Does anybody have an example found on the internet I could use to try? Or maybe a good, small example I can focus on?

Long story, I hoped I could make it smaller. I hope someone can help me with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When I need to support scenarios like this I have one "provisioning" or "configuration" database which holds the connectionstring for each customer/user/whatever. This is separate from the databases which map to the data my application needs.

Whenever the requests comes in you can configure your IOC container with the correct connectionstring, altough I don't know if unity supports this scenario, I know AutoFac / Ninject and most other containers allow changing the container.